# WooCommerce 3.0 get_price_html() alternate method

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I was using $product->get_price_html(); and after updating to WooCommerce 3.0
I'm having lots of warnings. I had a look into Woo 3.0 functions and find that **get_price_html** is deprecated

**Src:**
https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html

There is although a function that returns only price **get_price** but what if I want the formatted price with currency symbol?

Comment: The `get_price_html` method isn't deprecated. It has a deprecated argument but the method is fine to use. Do you have an example of the warnings you're seeing?

Comment: The get_price_html method isn't deprecated

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved by using wc_price($product->get_price()),

the notices I was seeing was

Notice: id was called incorrectly . Product properties should not be accessed directly. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.0.) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\functions.php on line 4137